# How to depend on a specific azure pipeline matrix job and not all of them?

Tags: azure-pipelines

in my setup I have a prepare, build, test and deploy job in a pipeline. Every of these jobs is using the same matrix configuration since the pipeline is processing the same src code for multiple configurations at the same time.

At the moment all the build jobs depend on the prepare jobs, all the test jobs on prepare, etc.

If now one prepare job (for one of the defined configurations) is failing all the subsequent build, test and deploy jobs are not executed. It is ok that for the improperly prepared configuration job there is no subsequent (same configuration) build, test and deployment.

But for all the other configurations where prepare or build or test could be finished successfully the subsequent configuration specific jobs should be running.

My idea was to specify configuration aware job dependencies but it seem this is not working or I am not doing it the right way.

Please provide a solution for this problem.

Thank you